# How to fix laravel form submit?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm tring to fix my form, so it adds new records into the database using laravel.
Right now, it does nothing more than refresh, when I push the submit button.
The validation process is also implemented.

The application does not throw any error either.

Does someone see what might be missing/wrong?

It is about the markets page.

My code:

markets.blade.php (view)

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Market List')


@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Markets</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form action="markets" method='post' class="row g-3">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>

                <input type="text" name='name' value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="adress" class="form-label">Adress</label>

                <input type="text" name='adress' value="{{ old('adress') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('adress') }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="City" class="form-label">City</label>

                <input type="text" name='City' value="{{ old('City') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('City') }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="province" class="form-label">Province</label>

                <input type="text" name='province' value="{{ old('province') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('province') }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="Country" class="form-label">Country</label>

                <input type="text" name='Country' value="{{ old('Country') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('Country') }}</div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="photo" class="form-label">Photo</label>
                <input type="file" name='photo' value="{{ old('photo') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('photo') }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>

                <input type="text" name='description' value="{{ old('description') }}" class="form-control">
                <div>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="active">Status</label>
                <select name="active" id="active" class="form-control" value="{{ old('active') }}">
                    <option value="" disabled>Select market status</option>
                    <option value="1" selected>Active</option>
                    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                </select>
                <div>{{ $errors->first('active') }}</div>
            </div>
            {{--<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Active</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="active" class="form-control" value="{{ old('active') }}" checked>

                  </div>
            </div>--}}


            {{--<div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_id">Market</label>
                <select name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control" value="{{ old('user_id') }}">
                    <option value="" disabled>Selecteer Market</option>
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>
            </div> --}}

            <div class="col-auto">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h3>Your Markets</h3>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($userMarkets as $userMarket)
                <li>{{ $userMarket->name }} <span class="text-muted">({{ $userMarket->adress - $userMarket->city }} - {{-- $userMarket->amountProducts --}} {{$userMarket->active}}</span></li>
            @endforeach

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

MarketsController.php (controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Validated;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MarketsController extends Controller
{
    public function list(){

        $userProducts = \App\Models\Product::user()->get();
        $userMarkets = \App\Models\Market::user()->get();

        return view("internal.markets", compact('userProducts', 'userMarkets'));
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'adress' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'province' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'photo' => '',
            'description' => 'max:300',
            'active' => 'boolean'
        ]);


        $market = new \App\Models\Market();
        $market->name = request('name');
        $market->adress = request('adress');
        $market->city = request('city');
        $market->province = request('province');
        $market->country = request('country');
        $market->photo = request('photo');
        $market->description = request('description');
        $market->active = request('active');
        $market->save();

        return back();

    }
}
```

Market.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Market extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function scopeActive($query){
        return $query->where('active', '1');
    }

    //filters on markets of logged in user
    public function scopeUser($query){

        //return $query->where('active', '1');

        return $query;
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Web.php (routes)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

//Products
Route::get('products', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@list');

Route::post('products', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@store');

//Markets
Route::get('markets', 'App\Http\Controllers\MarketsController@list');

Route::post('markets', 'App\Http\Controllers\MarketsController@store');
```

If someone sees the problem why is won't work. I'm happy to hear it.

Regards

Dave

Comment: Please try with this. `$this->validate($request, [//validation rule ]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several issues here. your form is missing the csrf token field. and some of your input names are starting with capital letter but you are validating with small letter. so the validation fails. and to be more precise add route name to your route and use that in the form action.

route

```
Route::post('markets', 'App\Http\Controllers\MarketsController@store')->name('markets.store');
```

and then in form

```
<form action="{{ route('markets.store') }}" method='post' class="row g-3">
    @csrf
```

and be precise with the input name like

```
<input type="text" name='city' value="{{ old('city') }}" class="form-control">
```

> make sure every input name matches with the validation name and in old helper as well.

and use Request class to catch the inputs.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'name' => 'required',
        // other fields
    ));

    $market = new \App\Models\Market();
    $market->name = $request->name;
    // other inputs
    $market->save();

    return redirect()
        ->route('any-route-you-want')
        ->with('success', 'Created Successfully');
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I didn't notice the capital letters, it is working.

Next time, I have to pay more attention to typos, when I have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is not working as you expect which appears to be due to a casing issue between your form field names, and the validation keys.

In your form you have `City` and `Country` but your validation is trying to validate against `city` and `country` which are throwing an error but, because your view is making use of capitals, the validation errors are not being shown. You also have a spelling error for `address`, but the spelling error is at least consistent.

Make your `City` and `Country` field names lowercase:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="city" class="form-label">Country</label>
    
  <input type="text" name="country" value="{{ old('city') }}" class="form-control">
  <div>{{ $errors->first("city") }}</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
    
  <input type="text" name="country" value="{{ old('country') }}" class="form-control">
  <div>{{ $errors->first("country") }}</div>
</div>
```

You can also pass your validated data straight to your model rather than assigning each attribute individually:

```
$data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'adress' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'province' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'photo' => '',
            'description' => 'max:300',
            'active' => 'boolean'
        ]);

$model = new Model($data);
$model->save();
```